# A expressão "tais que" está gramaticalmente correta neste caso?

Tags: gramática, sintaxe, classe-gramatical

A expressão *"tais que"* é muito comum principalmente na forma de uma locução conjuncional, portanto sendo gramaticalmente invariável e, portanto, gramaticalmente incorreta (o certo, geralmente, é *"tal que"*).

Agora, a seguinte frase seria incorreta?

> "A reta é o conjunto de pontos tais que são alinhados entre si."

Quais as funções semântica e sintática da expressão *"tais que"* na frase destacada (ou do termo isolado *"tais"*)?

Comment: Acho que mesmo _tal que_ não funciona aqui. Talvez _um conjunto de pontos distribuídos tal que (=de forma que) estão alinhados entre si_ ou _um conjunto de pontos tal que os pontos estão alinhados entre si_. A sequência _tais que_ existe, mas com outros significados: _Os pontos são tais que..._, _atingem proporções tais que..._ (= _atingem tais proporções que..._).

Comment: Talvez não advenha de "tal que", mas poderia haver uma vírgula entre "tais" e "que"? De qualquer forma, a frase é ruim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nah, a frase não está bem.
Eu escrevê-la-ia assim:

> Uma reta é um conjunto de pontos alinhados entre si.

---

## Sem *tais que*

Nessa frase (a original) não cabe o "tais que", [como explica o Artefacto num comentário](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/8347/a-express%c3%a3o-tais-que-est%c3%a1-gramaticalmente-correta-neste-caso#comment18922_8347):

> Acho que mesmo *tal que* não funciona aqui. Talvez «um conjunto de pontos distribuídos tal que (=de forma que) estão alinhados entre si» ou «um conjunto de pontos tal que os pontos estão alinhados entre si». A sequência *tais que* existe, mas com outros significados: «Os pontos são tais que...», «atingem proporções tais que...» (= *atingem tais proporções que...*).

## Sem *são*

A frase não precisa do "são". Vejo 3 formas diferentes de a re-organizar:

> - A reta é o conjunto de pontos alinhados entre si.
> - A reta é o conjunto de pontos que são* alinhados entre si. (Esta não me agrada.)
> - A reta é o conjunto de pontos que estão alinhados entre si.

## Devia usar artigos indefinidos

E a frase devia usar artigos indefinidos ("um", "uma") em vez de artigos definidos ("A", "o"):

> Uma reta é um conjunto de pontos alinhados entre si.

O uso de artigos definidos só seria apropriado: se a frase mencionasse uma reta específica - a reta que se procura, ou aquela reta ali, um uma daquelas ali; e se a frase mencionasse pontos específicos: dos pontos que estão em contexto, a reta seria o conjunto deles que estão alinhados entre si.

Mas não creio que a frase tenha sido escrita no contexto de um conjunto específico e definido de pontos, ou no contexto de uma ou várias retas específicas, ou de uma reta específica que se procura.